# Is it possible to extend generic Function prototype?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

It is possible to extend the Array prototype like so:

```
declare global {
    interface Array<T> {
        foo(bar: T) => void): Array<T>;
    }
}
```

and then call

```
([1,2,3]).foo(4); // type of array is infered
```

I can do the same for functions like:

```
declare global {
    interface Function {
        foo(...args: any): any
    }
}
```

But I dont have access to the function types.
I would rather do somathing like this:

```
declare global {
    interface Function<Tfunction> {
        foo(...args: Parameters<Tfunction>): ReturnType<Tfunction>
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get that type information?

I am not asking for how to implement these functions, but how to let typescript know what types the have.

Comment: The first declaration does not match how you want to call that method in the second code block. So, *yes* you can extend the Array interface like that. And *yes* you can call that method like that. Not both at the same time, though. Also just in case - the declaration only allows calling the extended method. You still do need to *implement it*. And with *that* said, it's generally unadvisable to change built-in globals.

Comment: @VLAZ Yeah your are right. I changed the question. And I know you still have to implement the functions of course. I am asking just out of curiosity. I dont plan to use it for something.

Comment: Try [this](https://tsplay.dev/WGPY0w)